# XSL how do i test a boolean data type?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am trying to test an attribute which is defined in the schema as a Boolean data type. The XML is dynamically created and if the value in the XML is 1, I simply want to print something. But nothing is printing.

Here is the schema

```
<xs:element name="Data">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> 
                        <xs:element id="variable" name="variable" type="xs:boolean" />
                      </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
```

Here is the XML

```
<Data>
                    <variable>1</variable>
                    <variable2>0</variable2>
                    <variable3>1</variable3>
                  </Data>
```

I have tried various ways. Here is what I have tried (I tried WHEN and IF)

```
<xsl:choose>        
                    <xsl:when test="variable = '1'">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="variable = 1">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="variable = 'true'">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@variable = 1">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@variable = '1'">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@variable = true">Print something</xsl:when> 
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <!--nothing-->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                  <xsl:if test="variable = '1'">Print something</xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="variable = 'true'">Print something</xsl:if>
```

My XSL starts with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

Comment: Please provide minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and output you get and the one you want to allow us to reproduce the problem. http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cj works as expected for me.

Comment: Context is everything in XSLT.  The `variable=1` and `variable='1'` tests should both work _provided_ the current context node is the `Data` element, _and_ there are no namespaces involved. Is that the complete XML or is it just a fragment of the whole, and if it's a fragment, does an ancestor element have a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`)?

Comment: To @IanRoberts. I am not sure what you mean, but there is no namespace. It just begins with <root>

Comment: Relative XPath expressions like `variable` resolve against the current _context item_, we need to see enough of the stylesheet to work out what context you're in. The tests you have already will work if they are under a `template match="Data"`, for example, but not if they're in a `template match="/"`

Comment: They are in a template match="/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: unless you are using a schema-aware processor, it doesn't really matter what your schema says.

Next, if you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor, as your stylesheet declares, then you can see if a value is true or false by applying the following test:

```
test="xs:boolean(value)"
```

For example, given the following test input:

**XML**

```
<Data>
    <variable>1</variable>
    <variable>0</variable>
    <variable>true</variable>
    <variable>false</variable>
</Data>
```

and applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="variable">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:choose>        
                    <xsl:when test="xs:boolean(.)">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--nothing-->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the following **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <variable>Print something</variable>
   <variable/>
   <variable>Print something</variable>
   <variable/>
</result>
```

which corresponds to what [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean) defines as the allowed values for a boolean data type.

---

**Are you really using an XSLT 2.0 processor?**

I have a good reason to doubt that: your stylesheet also declares a Microsoft namespace:

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

and AFAIK there are no Microsoft XSLT 2.0 processors.

To perform the same test in XSLT 1.0, you will need to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="variable">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:choose>        
                    <xsl:when test="number(.) or .='true'">Print something</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--nothing-->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can be sure that the value of `variable` will *always* be only either 1 or 0, then you can shorten the test to:

```
<xsl:when test="number(.)">
```